# web application token get DEVELOPER_ERROR react native @react-native-google-signin/google-signin

Tags: reactjs, react-native, gradle, google-signin

I have implemented this library ([@react-native-google-signin/google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin)) and it works perfectly fine for a period, but now i get this error: **DEVELOPER_ERROR**

`GoogleSignin.configure({ webClientId: clientId, offlineAccess: true, });`

clientId: application web token
Environment
react-native version "0.69.1"
"react": "18.0.0",
@react-native-google-signin/google-signin version:"^8.2.1"
Android, gradle :7.3.3

- I checked my token is active in google console.
  Did anyone experience any similar issues?

Thanks.

signin with google in react native

Comment: I tested the package on a different project but it doesn't work
"react-native": "0.71.8",
"react": "18.2.0",
"@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^10.0.1",

Comment: solved
i generating the APK by using keystore Win i removed  is now functioning.
Probably is keystore validity
ps : auth without firebase